# How to Fix error if I run mange.py run server Django version 1.11

Tags: python, django

If I want to run my manage.py runserver it generates an error

```
File "c:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py", line 151
    ('%s=%s') % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
    ^
Syntax Error: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

Comment: Use a more modern version... If you are indeed using Django 1.11 - that's errr... well over a decade old now... it won't work any Python 3 version.

Comment: Actually, Django 1.11 should work with Python 3 up to and including verison 3.7. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/install/#faq-python-version-support . 3.9 is certainly not supported officially, nor is Django 1.11 supported anymore: security issues will not have fixes anymore, so don't use it.

Comment: That syntax (taking the full line of code from https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L152 ) should actually work, even with 3.9, so something else is going on, on your side.

Comment: I spoke too soon: it was an error, and fixed in the most recent release. See https://github.com/django/django/commit/568c2f45ef531257a600c0e6ff8fe02525d7ab4e#diff-6c1fd2d8e05936979dbe3cedc5fb6df970e6044ef524078155cd8835833008c7 .

Comment: All in all: ditch 1.11 entirely, and start with Django 3.2. *If* (that is a big if) you have to use 1.11 (perhaps because you want to migrate step by step towards 3.2), upgrade that to the very latest version first. That should fix this error.